# Pandas compare the same colums between merged dfs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dfs that look like the following:

Df1:

```
area       team     score
ontario    team 1   60
ontario    team 3   30
ontario    team 2   50
new york   team 1   90
new york   team 2   30
```

Df2:

```
area       team     score
ontario    team 1   60
ontario    team 3   30
ontario    team 2   50
new york   team 1   90
new york   team 2   70
```

If I do the following:

```
merge = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['area', 'team'])
```

I get:

merge:

```
area       team     score_x  score_y
ontario    team 1   60       60
ontario    team 3   30       30
ontario    team 2   50       50
new york   team 1   90       90
new york   team 2   30       70
```

It can be noted that the score in the last row of both dfs is different.
I would like to find what the percent difference is in between score_x and score_y.

However I actually have hundreds of metrics such as "score". How can I find the percent difference of each column of the merged df which has the same key before the merge is done and the _x and _y are apended?

Whats the best way to do this? I guess I could just get a list of the common keys and append a _y and _x to each and then go through the list and check the percent difference of both columns, but is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set 'area' and 'team' as the frame index and do the "normal" math:

```
df1.set_index(['area','team'], inplace=True)
df2.set_index(['area','team'], inplace=True)

(df1 - df2) / df1
#                    score  
#area     team                    
#ontario  team 1  0.000000  
#         team 3  0.000000   
#         team 2  0.000000    
#new york team 1  0.000000    
#         team 2 -1.333333
```